# Pythonのパッケージを一括でアップデートするプログラムをマルチスレッドで書く

Tags: python

Pythonでスレッドを用いて一括で全パッケージのアップデートをしたいと思っています。
しかし、下記のコードは[GoルーチンやPythonでマルチスレッドで実行した時](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7441/golang%E3%81%A7python%E3%81%AE%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%92%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)のように早くなりません。なぜ、遅くなってしまうのでしょうか?

```
    
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4
import subprocess
import os
import threading
import re


def update(package_name):
    os.system("pip3.4 install " + package_name + " -U")

s = subprocess.check_output(["pip3.4", "freeze"]).decode()
package_list = re.findall(".+(?===)", s)
package_list.extend(["pip", "setuptools"])
print(package_list)

for v in package_list:
    threading.Thread(target=update, args=(v,)).start()
```

Comment: ちなみに、`pip`はpythonなんで、通常のpythonのように`import`ができるようです。　http://blog.ducky.io/python/2013/08/22/calling-pip-programmatically/

Comment: importしてやってみましたがエラーが出ました。

Comment: そもそもの前提として、`pip install `を並列実行すると「速く」なるのでしょうか？ディスクI/Oやネットワーク帯域は限られます（というか物理的に１個）から、期待通りpipプロセスが並列起動されても、必ずしも全体処理が速くなる保証はありません。また並列起動数にも上限値を設けないと、並列化オーバーヘッドばかりが増大して結果的には遅くなります。

Comment: GILを解除するのに時間がかかっていることは考えられるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 3):

これは回答ではないのですが、Python の GIL について、例えば以下のコードを実行すると、

```
from threading import Thread
import os

def sleep(n):
  os.system("date; echo " + str(n) + "; sleep 1")

for n in range(0,10):
  Thread(target=sleep, args=(n,)).start()
```

結果は以下の様になります。

```
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
0
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
1
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
3
4
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
5
2
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
7
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
8
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
6
Fri Mar  6 22:30:35 JST 2015
9
```

どうやら、`os.system()` の実行時には GIL が外される様です。

[Message 103280 - Python tracker](http://bugs.python.org/msg103280)

> It locks the buffer because os.system() releases the GIL when calling system().

Comment: [ソースコード](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c#L2632-L2634)を見たらGILを解放してたので、遅いのは別の原因ですね。GIL関連で何かオーバーヘッドがあるのかもしれませんが。